# Parse Shortcodes in Theme's Custom Field?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I have a theme which has a "PRICE" custom field that only accepts numerical values. Is there anyway to parse shortcodes in that custom field so I can dynamically display the price using another plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function.

```
do_shortcode('[your-shortcode option1=foo option2=bar]');
```

Or in your case:

```
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', true);

#Dynamically generate the plugin shortcode
$new_price = do_shortcode("[plugin-shortcode price=$price]");
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm a complete noob when it comes to WordPress functions. Do I just input the above code into my functions file, and then the shortcodes will begin to work when inputted into that custom field? Sorry for such a noob question, still learning WordPress -- and thank you for the help.

Comment: well it depends to where you want to output the shortcode. Than put the code above.

Comment: -1 Downvote. The question relates to parsing the shortcode in the custom fields value field, not in the code. Also, don't do  shortcode as its not efficient http://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but an edit would have been a better option here on a three year old question @BradDalton